# How to run WriteToJdbc Beam transform on DataFlow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to execute Beam pipeline on DataFlow runner. The pipeline includes WriteToJdbc transform module, which is configured to write into PostgreSQL database. The pipeline definition is stored on my local machine and executed using:

```
python *module name* --some options
```

The execution gets stucked on *INFO:apache_beam.internal.gcp.auth:socket default timeout is 60.0 seconds.* Can somebody advise what might be the reason?

I expect the pipeline to be executed on DataFlow. Have tried to check the logs but did not find anything useful there.

Comment: Have you tried to go through this simple example first? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/create-pipeline-python, which helps setup all the permissions.

Comment: I did, no success. Thanks for the suggestion though.